# Obtaining Individual Tree predictions using randomForestSRC

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction

Is there a way to obtain individual tree predictions similar to the original randomForest R package? I currently need the individual predictions to derive probabilistic prediction ranges. If there isn't an inherent function in randomForestSRC, are there lines of code that can do the job quickly? This would be of immense help!

*Context: I used to use randomForest but it has limitations on the number of levels in factor you can use for a categorical variable and since switched over to randomForestSRC.